# Get constraints and indexes on materialized views

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, materialized-views

Query to get all indexes and all constraints on all materialized views in Postgres. The below query only returns indexes on tables.

```
SELECT indexname, indexdef 
FROM pg_indexes 
WHERE schemaname = 'public' AND tablename = 'table'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view [`pg_indexes`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-indexes.html) provides access to useful information about **each** index in the database (also indexes on materialized views). You can lookup [`pg_class`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html) to filter out only materialized views (`relkind = 'm'`):

```
select i.*
from pg_indexes i
join pg_class c
    on schemaname = relnamespace::regnamespace::text 
    and tablename = relname
where relkind = 'm'

 schemaname | tablename |    indexname    | tablespace |                             indexdef                             
------------+-----------+-----------------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------------
 public     | my_view   | my_view_id_idx  |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_view_id_idx ON my_view USING btree (id)
 public     | sen_view  | sen_view_id_idx |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX sen_view_id_idx ON sen_view USING btree (id)
(2 rows)
```

Comment: This does not give me foreign key constraints.

Comment: 1. Foreign keys are not indexes. 2. You cannot define a foreign key on a materialized view.