# Is it possible to list indexes created on materialized views in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, indexing, materialized

I am able to to list all indexes on tables by using pg_indexes. This however, does not list the indexes created on the materialized view. Neither does the pgadmin3 frontend show the indexes on materialized views.

Is there a way?

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you using? I assume it is an old version since you are using pgAdmin3. With PostgreSQL v15.3 and pgAdmin4 v7.4, materialized view indexes are visible in the Object Explorer panel.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly (even though there's a lot of ambiguity), you can use the `pg_indexes` view to get information about indexes on materialized views. I used an example schema and query to verify that you can use to list all indexes on materialized views in the `public` schema:

```sql
-- Create a table
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    value NUMERIC NOT NULL
);

-- Insert some data into the table
INSERT INTO my_table (name, value)
VALUES ('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3);

-- Create a materialized view
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_view AS
SELECT name, SUM(value) as total_value
FROM my_table
GROUP BY name;

-- Create an index on the materialized view
CREATE INDEX my_view_name_idx ON my_view (name);

-- List indices
SELECT i.*
FROM pg_indexes i
JOIN pg_class c ON i.schemaname = c.relnamespace::regnamespace::text AND i.tablename = c.relname
WHERE c.relkind = 'm' AND i.schemaname = 'public';
```

This query joins the `pg_indexes` view with the `pg_class` table to filter out only materialized views (`relkind = 'm'`). You can modify the `WHERE` clause to filter the results based on your needs.

This was tested on PostgreSQL 14 (on Google Colab to be exact)
[image]

You can also refer to these for more insight

- [Get constraints and indexes on materialized views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57515765/get-constraints-and-indexes-on-materialized-views)
- [Materialized Views and Indexes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/137585/materialized-views-and-indexes)

Comment: Thanks. Maybe this is a version support issue. I am using 9.4 and it doesnt work on that. gives me the following issue : ERROR:  type "regnamespace" does not exist
LINE 3: JOIN pg_class c ON i.schemaname = c.relnamespace::regnamespa...

Comment: The pg_indexes doesnt show it - I had taken a select * and manually searched the output, before putting the query.